# Triple inner join with php and mysql with different databases

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening everyone, I have a big problem because if I'm not doing it right. Since I am concerned that this query does not throw me the correct information. I have 2 databases, 'indvalid_hya' and 'uuid_sap'.

In my database 'indvalid_hya' I have the following tables with the following fields:
This table has a primary key which is 'XML_ID' and is related to ID my table 'FILE'

```
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------+------+-------+------------+
| ISSUEDDATE | TOTAL | ISSUERRFC | RECEIVERRFC | UUID | FOLIO | XML_ID (PK)|
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------+------+-------+------------+
|            |       |           |             |      |       |            |
+------------+-------+-----------+-------------+------+-------+------------+
```

This is my other table 'DOCUMENT' in the same BD 'Indvalid_hya':

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|   ID (FK)  |     BYTES    | ISSUERRFC | 
+------------+--------------+-----------+
|            |              |           |
+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

And finally I have my other database which is called 'uuid_sap'. I have 3 bosses there he held related to the other 2 tables using the 'ID'.
Table 'DATOS_SAP':

```
+----------------+---------+-----------+
| UUID_SAP (FK)  | NUM_DOC |  SOCIETY  |
+----------------+---------+-----------+
|                |         |           | 
+----------------+---------+-----------+
```

And this is my code that binds my table 'DOCUMENT' and 'FILE' my BD 'Indvalid_hya' with my other BD 'uuid_sap' my table 'DATOS_SAP'

My code MySQL:

```
SELECT IH.ISSUEDDATE, IH.TOTAL, IH.ISSUERRFC, IH.RECEIVERRFC, IH.UUID, IH.FOLIO, F.BYTES, US.UUID_SAP 
FROM indvalid_hya.DOCUMENT IH 
INNER JOIN FILE F
ON IH.XML_ID = F.ID
INNER JOIN uuid_sap.DATOS_SAP US
ON IH.UUID = US.UUID_SAP
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, if I'm wrong let me here you know

```
SELECT DB1_T1.ISSUEDDATE, DB1_T1.TOTAL, DB1_T1.ISSUERRFC, DB1_T1.RECEIVERRFC, DB1_T1.UUID, DB1_T1.FOLIO, DB2_T1.UUID_SAP 
    FROM indvalid_hya.DOCUMENT DB1_T1
    INNER JOIN  indvalid_hya.FILE DB1_T2
    ON DB1_T1.XML_ID = DB1_T2.ID
    INNER JOIN uuid_sap.DATOS_SAP DB2_T1
    ON DB1_T1.UUID = DB2_T1.UUID_SAP
```